ZSH function output to current prompt input is ignored
I have a registered function in ZSH that searches file contents under the current path for a match and then captures the resulting filename. This is then bound to a key combination. The keybinding, search and result all work fine (as in they return the desired value).
When I am using the keybinding, the value is printed out to the current shell line but it is not recognised as actual input (i.e. if I hit enter the value is considered empty and nothing is added to the prompt history). How do I output the result as if it were typed and a valid value. I have have attempted echo/print/printf (assuming the outcome would be the same for each) but also appending to BUFFER and setting CURSOR.
I'm sure this is well documented and I'm failing to find examples because of the lack of correct terminology. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Printing to the terminal can't help you. That displays a message for the user (it won't be in the right place on the screen and will confuse the line editor because it changes the terminal's cursor position — use zle -M or zle -R instead). That's not input for the shell.
The magic variable BUFFER contains the line(s) that the user is editing, and CURSOR contains the input cursor position. You can change the user input buffer and the cursor position by modifying BUFFER and CURSOR. So you were on the right track there. To insert something at the cursor, though, there's an easier way: just append to the magic variable LBUFFER and zsh will do the rest. LBUFFER contains the user input up to the cursor, and modifying it works intuitively.
Here's a working example from my .zshrc of inserting the output of a command into the input buffer. It inserts the current Git branch name when I press Alt+v b.
vc_insert_branch () {
  LBUFFER+=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2>/dev/null)
}
zle -N vc_insert_branch
bindkey '^[vb' vc_insert_branch

Note that this simple example inserts the output of the command as is. For a file name, you should probably quote it in case it has special characters. For example, if the command's output is A Song.mp3 then the simple code above just inserts A Song.mp3 into the command line. But to make it useful, it should insert something that's a valid argument to a command. Use the q- or q+ parameter expansion flag to quote the command's output if necessary.
insert_file_search_result () {
  LBUFFER+=${(q-)$(search command goes here 2>/dev/null)}
}

Note that if you'd like to do a search based on the word around the cursor, zsh has helper functions that save you from doing your own command line parsing, and they can also take care of injecting new text. In particular, modify-current-argument replaces the shell word around the cursor by a new shell word of your choice, which it quotes if necessary. Here's a proof-of-concept that shows how to replace the word that the cursor is in by the most recent file containing that word.
function grep_word_and_reply_with_file_name {
  if [[ -z $ARG ]]; then
    zle -M 'Cursor not in a word'
    return 1
  fi
  local -a files
  files=(${(@0)${$(grep -l -Z -F -e $ARG -- /dev/null *(-.DNom))%$'\000'}})
  if (($#files == 0)); then
    zle -M "No match for $ARG"
    return 1
  fi
  REPLY=$files[1]
}

function grep_word_and_replace_with_file_name {
  autoload -Uz modify-current-argument
  modify-current-argument grep_word_and_reply_with_file_name
}
zle -N grep_word_and_replace_with_file_name
bindkey '\eG' grep_word_and_replace_with_file_name


Thank you for the complete answer with some other considerations I have missed. I'll get my script updated

Typically I found my answer on the next thing I looked at.
I found some inspiration from https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.zsh - in particular the fzf-history-widget function. There it sets the LBUFFER variable with the user input (if not a revision history command) and then calls zle reset-prompt. I tested this with my BUFFER + CURSOR approach and that works too but the LBUFFER approach is more concise.

Yes, LBUFFER+=value to insert value to the Left of the cursor is quite canonical.
